# Проблемы с сайтом после заливки на хостинг

Tags: php, mysql

Решил попробовать залить сайт на хостинг,

```
<?php
require 'rb.php';
$data = $_POST;
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=БД','Юзер','Пароль');
//там всё 999% правильно введено
if (isset($data['do_signup'])) {
  $user = R::dispense('users');
  $user->login = $data['username'];
  $user->password = $data['password'];
  R::store($user);
  echo "Hello!";
}
?>
```

Код точно правильный, в OpenServеr работал отлично, после залил на 000webhost, добавил бд в настройках, всё норм, но при попытке зайти на сайт вылазит много букв :([image: ошибка]

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(имя БД, пароль и т.д.);
if ($connection == false){
  echo "Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!";
  die();
}
```

Этот код сообщение об ошибке не выводит(!)

Версия php на сайте та же что и была на локалке, что делать?

Comment: "много букв" ну капец... видно же, что "Access denied" = имя юзера БД на хостинге неверное, или пароль его, или имя самой БД (вряд ли будет именно такая ошибка), от этого и пляшите и правьте либо БД либо код этот

Comment: Имя юзера и пароль скопировал(точно правильные), да и вручную я могу в phpnyadmin зайти, а код не может

Comment: а хост там локалхост ли?

Comment: и что за странный формат этой строки? имя БД, логин и пароль через запятую вперемешку

Comment: Имя, которое вы замазали красным, в сообщении об ошибке совпадают с вашими?

Comment: @MaximKravetc Да, совпадает полностью

Comment: Да, хост — локалхост, так указано на сайте

Comment: @Rou1997 В RedBean php так можно(проверял)

Comment: У Вас было `R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='БД','Юзер','Пароль');` Возможно проблема из-за того, что параметр `dbname` принял значение **'БД**, либо Вы просто ошиблись при создании вопроса.

Comment: На хостингах бывает еще имени вашей базы добавляют префикс, т.е. вместо ожидаемого `БД` может оказаться `user25361563_БД`

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксическая ошибка, у вас кажется одинарная кавычка в пароле, поместите его в двойные, сделайте так:

```
$passwd = "вашпарольс'кавычками@dffdfdfdf'%";

R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=БД','Юзер',$passwd);
```

Либо добавьте символ \ перед кавычкой в строке, выполнив тем самым экранировку символа. Вот пример:

```
php -a
php > $a = 'dsfsdfsdfdsfdsf\'dssfdsf';
php > echo $a;
dsfsdfsdfdsfdsf'dssfdsf
```